# What are pros and cons of consuming web services with 1. events / 2. IAsyncResult?

Tags: c#, web-services, events, iasyncresult

I made a WPF example that consumes a **web service** ([www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx](http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx)) in two different ways:

with **events** like this:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

    Location = "loading...";
    Temperature = "loading...";
    RelativeHumidity = "loading...";

    client.GetWeatherCompleted += 
            new EventHandler<GetWeatherCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetWeatherCompleted);
    client.GetWeatherAsync("Berlin", "Germany");
}

void client_GetWeatherCompleted(object sender, GetWeatherCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

    Location = xdoc.Descendants("Location").Single().Value;
    Temperature = xdoc.Descendants("Temperature").Single().Value;
    RelativeHumidity = xdoc.Descendants("RelativeHumidity").Single().Value;
}
```

and with the **Begin/End methods and IAsyncResult** like this:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

    Location = "loading...";
    Temperature = "loading...";
    RelativeHumidity = "loading...";

    client.BeginGetWeather("Berlin", "Germany", new AsyncCallback(GotWeather), null);
}

void GotWeather(IAsyncResult result)
{
    string xml = client.EndGetWeather(result).ToString();
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    Location = xdoc.Descendants("Location").Single().Value;
    Temperature = xdoc.Descendants("Temperature").Single().Value;
    RelativeHumidity = xdoc.Descendants("RelativeHumidity").Single().Value;

}
```

These two approaches seem to perform the exact same task.

**What are their advantages and disadvantages? When would you use one and not the other?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case of remote services, I usually prefer to use callbacks instead of event handlers since it leads to more readable/maintainable code (by just looking at the service call invokation code I know which code will be executed when the call finishes). Moreover when using event handlers you need to have care for not declaring them more than once.

Answer (score 0):

That's just matter of taste. No difference from technical prospective.